# How Do I Turn Off Python Error Checking in vim? (vim terminal 7.3, OS X 10.11 Yosemite)

Tags: python, macos, vim, osx-yosemite

### Overview

After upgrading to 10.11 Yosemite, I discovered that vim (on the terminal) highlights a bunch of errors in my python scripts that are actually not errors.

#### e.g.

This line:

`from django.conf.urls import patterns`

gets called out as an `[import-error] Unable to import 'django.conf.urls'`.

This error is not true because I can open up a python shell from the command line and import the supposedly missing module. I'm also getting a bunch of other errors all the way through my python file too: `[bad-continuation] Wrong continued indentation`, `[invalid-name] Invalid constant name`, etc.

All of these errors are not true.

### Question

Anyway, how do I turn off these python error checks?

#### vim Details

`vim --version`:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov  5 2014 21:00:28)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? Can you post your .vimrc?

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I've realized based on your comment that I have Syntastic installed, via `pathogen`. Looking up the settings there now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked up options for `syntastic` and set it up so that it only uses the basic `python` syntax checker. That did the trick. I'm still not sure which ones were screwing me up, but I'm okay with that for now. I'll be happy to select your answer if you type it up and enter one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim doesn't check Python syntax out of the box, so a plugin is probably causing this issue.

Not sure why an OS upgrade would make a Vim plugin suddenly start being more zealous about things, of course, but your list of installed plugins (however you manage them) is probably the best place to start narrowing down your problem.